# Javascript animation not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I have a code which fades is words one by one. Code is modified a bit from demo. Demo is here: http://thenewcode.com/1178/Create-a-Word-Fade-In-Effect-Using-the-Web-Animation-API

The code:

```
function fadeWords(thequote) {
    time=0;
    first = true;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(thequote, function(word,i) {
    timspan=  i * 150;
    let animate = word.animate([{
      opacity: 0,
      filter: "blur("+getRandom(2,5)+"px)"
    }, {
      opacity: 1,
      filter: "blur(0px)"
    }], 
    { 
      duration: 600,
      delay: timspan,
      fill: 'forwards'
    } 
   )

  })
}
```

Safari gives me error: undefined is not a function (near '...word.animate...')

If I take away the modifications I did, the demo still doesn't work in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not supported in Safari:
Check browser compatibility:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility

Or https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation

You need to use polyfill to make your code work: https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js

Comment: Thank you, sir! Your help is much appreciated :)